# Implementing SKI conversion - prove that returning value has promised type

Tags: coq

I'm trying to implement a function `extract` which takes an expression like `(f (g x y))` together with a variable e.g. `y` and produces a function `y --> (f (g x y))` with SKI combinators. In this case, the result should be `(S (K f) (g x))`.

In some sense, I'm doing a [conversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatory_logic#Completeness_of_the_S-K_basis) from lambda term to its SKI version.

I'm trying to do a typed version of this and I'm having hard times.

---

### Set up

Types in these expressions are represented by the following inductive type

```
Inductive type : Type :=
| base_type    : forall (n : nat), type
| arrow_type   : type -> type -> type.
```

Basically, I have some basic types indexed by integers(`base_type`) and also I can create function types between them (`arrow_type`)

Introduce notation for function types

```
Notation "A --> B" := (arrow_type A B) (at level 30, right associativity).
```

Expression are represented by the following inductive type

```
Inductive term : type -> Type :=

| var    : forall (n : nat) (A : type), term A
| eval   : forall {A B : type}, term (A-->B) -> term A -> term B

| I      : forall (A : type)    , term (A --> A)
| K      : forall (A B : type)  , term (A --> (B --> A))
| S      : forall (A X Y : type), term ((A --> X --> Y) --> (A --> X) --> A --> Y).
```

Here, I have again set of basic variables indexed by integers `n : nat` and a type `A : type` (not `Type`!)

Thus, a variable `x : term X` is an expression with `type` `X`.

To reduce eyesore, let's introduce notation for function evaluation

```
Notation "f [ x ]" := (eval f x) (at level 25, left associativity).
```

---

### Introductory example

The original question can be stated more precisely as follows.

Let's start with defining with some types

```
Notation X := (base_type 0).
Notation Y := (base_type 1).
```

Define variables `x y` and functions `f g` (they can be all indexed with 0 because they all have different `type`)

```
Notation x := (var 0 X).
Notation y := (var 0 Y).
Notation g := (var 0 (X --> Y --> X)).
Notation f := (var 0 (X --> Y)).
```

The `type` of the resulting expression is `Y`.

```
Check f[g[x][y]].
```

My goal is to produce a function `extract` such that

```
extract f[g[x][y]] y
```

produces

```
S[K[f]][g[x]]
```

with type filled in

```
(S Y X Y)[(K (X-->Y) Y)[f]][g[x]]
```

---

### Equality on `type` and `term`

To proceed with an attempt to define `extract` I need to define equality on `type` and `term`.

```
Require Import Arith.EqNat.
Open Scope bool_scope.

Fixpoint eq_type (A B : type) : bool :=
  match A, B with
  | base_type n,    base_type m      => beq_nat n m
  | arrow_type X Y, arrow_type X' Y' => (eq_type X X') && (eq_type Y Y')
  | _, _  => false                                                      
  end.

Fixpoint eq_term {A B : type} (a : term A) (b : term B) : bool :=
  match a, b with
  | var n X      , var n' X'        => (beq_nat n n') && (eq_type X X')
  | eval X Y f x , eval X' Y' f' x' => (eq_type X X') && (eq_type Y Y') && (eq_term f f') && (eq_term x x')
  | I  X         , I X'             => (eq_type X X')
  | K X Y        , K X' Y'          => (eq_type X X') && (eq_type Y Y')
  | S Z X Y      , S Z' X' Y'       => (eq_type X X') && (eq_type Y Y') && (eq_type Z Z')
  | _            , _                => false                                   
  end.
```

---

### Attempt at implementing `extract`

The 'implementation' is quite straightforward

```
Fixpoint extract {A B : type} (expr : term B) (val : term A) : term (A-->B) :=
  if (eq_term expr val)
  then (I A)
  else 
    match expr with
    | eval X Y f x => (S A X Y)[extract f val][extract x val]
    | _            => (K B A)[expr]
    end.
```

There are two problems

1. When returning `I A`: `type` of `I A` is `A --> A` not `A --> B` as promised, but in that particular case I should be able to prove that `B` and `A` are the same.
2. When returning `(S A X Y)[...`: the returning value is `A --> Y` and not `A --> B`, but again I should be able to prove that `Y` is equal to `B`.

How can I prove `B=A` and `Y=B` in those particular cases such that the function definition is accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is turn `eq_type` and `eq_term` from boolean functions into decision procedures for equality.  Currently, as far as I can tell, your equality is entirely syntactic.  So you could simply use Coq's notion of equality to talk about equality of terms and types.  Then, you can write:

```
Definition eq_type_dec (A B : type) : { A = B } + { A <> B }.
```

You pretty much do the pattern match on `A` and `B`, then return `left eq_refl` for the cases of equality, and `right ...` in the other cases, where `...` is whatever you need to do to prove disequality.

Do the same and define `eq_term_dec`.  You have two choices here, either making the equality of types intrinsic or extrinsic:

```
Definition eq_term_dec (A B : type) (a : A) (b : B) :
  { (A = B) * (existT (fun t => t) A a = existT (fun t => t) B b) }
  +
  { (A <> B) + (existT (fun t => t) A a <> existT (fun t => t) B b) }.
```

or:

```
Definition eq_term_dec (A : type) (a b : term A) : { a = b } + { a <> b }.
```

The first one seems pretty awful to write, but gives you more flexibility.  I'd probably favor the latter, and use it under a `eq_type_check` when dealing with possibly-unequal types.

Once you have those, you can turn your `if` into a dependent `match`:

```
Fixpoint extract {A B : type} (expr : term B) (val : term A) : term (A-->B) :=
  match eq_type_dec A B with
  | left eqAB =>
    match eqAB
          in eq _ B1
          return term B1 -> term (A --> B1)
    with
    | eq_refl => fun expr1 => (* now expr1 : A *)
      match eq_expr_dec _ _ expr1 val with
      | left eqab => I A
      | right neqab => (* ... *)
      end
    end expr (* note here we pass the values that must change type *)
  | right neqAB => (* ... *)
  end.
```

There might still be quite a bit of work in the branches I have elided. You might look at different ways of doing such dependently-typed programming, either manually like I have shown here, or using dependent elimination tactics, or using the recursors of those types.

---

**EDIT**

To answer your comment, here are twp ways I know of writing `eq_term_dec`.  One way is to use the `Program` extension of Coq, which adds one axiom and becomes much more capable of dealing with dependent types:

```
Require Import Program.Equality.

Fixpoint eq_term_dec (A : type) (a b : term A) : { a = b } + { a <> b }.
  dependent induction a; dependent induction b; try (right ; congruence).
  - destruct (PeanoNat.Nat.eq_dec n n0); [ left | right ]; congruence.
```

The other way is to actually figure out the dependently-typed term you need.  There has to be a way of doing so using tactics, but I'm not quite sure how to proceed, however, I know how to write the term.  It is not for the faint of heart, and I don't expect you to understand what's going on until after you have become familiar with dependent pattern-matching and the "convoy pattern".  Here it is if you want to see what this looks like:

```
Fixpoint eq_term_dec (A : type) (a b : term A) : { a = b } + { a <> b }.
  revert b.
  destruct a.
  {
    destruct b; try (right ; congruence).
    destruct (PeanoNat.Nat.eq_dec n n0) ; [ left | right ] ; congruence.
  }
  { destruct b; admit. (* skipping this, it's easy *) }
  {
    (* Here is the complication:                                                  *)
    (* `b` has type `term (A -> A)`                                               *)
    (* If you abstract over its type, the goal is ill-typed, because the equality *)
    (* `I A = b` is at type `A -> A`.                                             *)
    intros b.

    refine (
        (fun (T : type) (ia : term T) (b : term T) =>
           match b
                 as b1
                 in term T1
                 return forall (ia0 : term T1),
                          match T1 as T2 return term T2 -> term T2 -> Type with
                          | arrow_type Foo Bar => fun ia1 b2 => {ia1 = b2} + {ia1 <> b2}
                          | _ => fun _ _ => True
                          end ia0 b1
           with
           | var n a  => fun b => _
           | eval h a => fun b => _
           | I A      => fun b => _
           | K A B    => fun b => _
           | S A B C  => fun b => _
           end ia
        ) (A --> A) (I A) b
      ).

    (* from now on it's easy to proceed *)
    destruct a.
    easy.
    destruct b; try ( right ; congruence ).
    destruct (PeanoNat.Nat.eq_dec n n0) ; [ left | right ] ; congruence.

    (* one more to show it's easy *)
    destruct t0.
    easy.
    destruct b; try ( right ; congruence ).

    (* etc... *)
```

Comment: I have managed to implement `eq_type_dec` but I'm having trouble implementing/proving `eq_term_dec`(the second version). When I start with `Proof. case a.` I get an error `Abstracting over the terms "A" and "a" leads to a term "fun (A : type) (a : term A) => {a = b} + {a <> b}" which is ill-typed.` I'm having hard time to decipher what that really means.

Comment: I've updated my answer with some hints as to how one could go about this.

Comment: Thanks! I will study that. So far, I have actualy managed to implement the first version of `eq_term_dec`, but I had to add the `eq_rect_eq` axiom.

Comment: @Ptrival Thanks again for the help! My head is still struggling with dependent pattern-matching, so I have implemented everything with tactics. However, your answer nudged me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution, it is not pretty but it seems to work. Especially, the proof of `eq_term_dec` is super long and ugly.

If anyone is interested, my solution:

```
Inductive type : Type :=
| base_type    : forall (n : nat), type
| arrow_type   : type -> type -> type.

Notation "A --> B" := (arrow_type A B) (at level 30, right associativity).
Inductive term : type -> Type :=

| var    : forall (n : nat) (A : type), term A
| eval   : forall {A B : type}, term (A-->B) -> term A -> term B

| I      : forall {A : type}    , term (A --> A)
| K      : forall {A B : type}  , term (A --> (B --> A))
| S      : forall {A X Y : type}, term ((A --> X --> Y) --> ((A --> X) --> (A --> Y))).

(* Coercion term : type >-> Sortclass. *)

Notation "n :: A" := (var n A).
Notation "f [ x ]" := (eval f x) (at level 25, left associativity).

Fixpoint eq_type_dec (A B : type) : {A = B} + {A <> B}.
Proof.
  decide equality.
  decide equality.
Defined.

Require Import Coq.Logic.Eqdep.

Fixpoint eq_term_dec {A B : type} (a : term A) (b : term B) :
  ( (A = B) * (existT (fun T : type => term T) A a = existT (fun T : type => term T) B b) )
  +
  ( (A <> B) + (existT (fun T : type => term T) A a <> existT (fun T : type => term T) B b) ).
Proof.
  case a as [n X| X Y f x | X | X Y | Z X Y], b as [n' X'| X' Y' f' x' | X' | X' Y' | Z' X' Y'].

  (* var n X ? var n' X'*)
  - assert (ndec : {n=n'} + {n<>n'}) by decide equality.
    pose (Xdec := eq_type_dec X X').

    destruct ndec as [eqn | neqn], Xdec as [eqX | neqX].
    left.
    rewrite eqn.
    rewrite eqX.
    split; reflexivity.

    right; left.  apply neqX.
    right; right. 
    intro H; inversion H as [H1]. auto.
    right; left. apply neqX.

  - right; right; intro H; inversion H. (* n ?  f[x] *)
  - right; right; intro H; inversion H. (* n ? I *)
  - right; right; intro H; inversion H. (* n ? K *)
  - right; right; intro H; inversion H. (* n ? S *)
  - right; right; intro H; inversion H. (* f[x] ? n *)

  - pose (xdec := eq_term_dec _ _ x x').
    pose (fdec := eq_term_dec _ _ f f').

    destruct xdec, fdec.

    (* x = x' && f = f' *)
    left.
    split.
    apply fst in p0.
    inversion p0.
    auto.

    apply snd in p0.
    inversion p0.

    revert dependent x.
    revert dependent f.
    rewrite H0.
    rewrite H1.
    intros.
    apply snd in p.
    assert (x=x'). apply inj_pair2; apply p.
    assert (f=f'). apply inj_pair2; apply p0.
    rewrite H, H3. auto.

    right.
    destruct s.
    left. intro.
    apply fst in p.
    assert (X-->Y = X' --> Y').
    rewrite H, p.
    auto. auto.

    right. intro.
    inversion H.
    apply n.
    revert dependent x.
    revert dependent f.
    rewrite H1.
    rewrite H2.
    intros.
    apply inj_pair2 in H4.
    apply inj_pair2 in H4.
    rewrite H4.
    auto.

    right.
    destruct s.
    inversion p.
    inversion H.
    auto.
    inversion p.
    inversion H0.
    revert dependent x.
    revert dependent f.
    rewrite H2.
    rewrite H3.
    intros.
    apply inj_pair2 in H0.
    rewrite H0.
    right.
    intro.
    apply inj_pair2 in H1.
    inversion H1. auto.

    destruct s, s0.
    right. right.
    intro. inversion H. auto.
    right. right.
    intro. inversion H. auto.
    right. right.
    intro. inversion H. auto.
    right. right.
    intro. inversion H. auto.

  - right; right; intro H; inversion H. (* f[x] ? I *)
  - right; right; intro H; inversion H. (* f[x] ? K *)
  - right; right; intro H; inversion H. (* f[x] ? S *)
  - right; right; intro H; inversion H. (* I ? n *)
  - right; right; intro H; inversion H. (* I ? f[x] *)

  - pose (Xdec := eq_type_dec X X'). (* I ? I *)

    destruct Xdec.

    left; split; rewrite e; auto.
    right; left. intro. inversion H. auto.

  - right; right; intro H; inversion H. (* I ? K *)
  - right; right; intro H; inversion H. (* I ? S *)
  - right; right; intro H; inversion H. (* K ? n *)
  - right; right; intro H; inversion H. (* K ? f[x] *)
  - right; right; intro H; inversion H. (* K ? I *)

  - pose (Xdec := eq_type_dec X X').
    pose (Ydec := eq_type_dec Y Y').

    destruct Xdec, Ydec.

    left; split; rewrite e; rewrite e0; auto.
    right; left; intro; inversion H; auto.
    right; left; intro; inversion H; auto.
    right; left; intro; inversion H; auto.

  - right; right; intro H; inversion H. (* K ? S *)
  - right; right; intro H; inversion H. (* S ? n *)
  - right; right; intro H; inversion H. (* S ? f[x] *)
  - right; right; intro H; inversion H. (* S ? I *)
  - right; right; intro H; inversion H. (* S ? K *)

  - pose (Xdec := eq_type_dec X X').
    pose (Ydec := eq_type_dec Y Y').
    pose (Zdec := eq_type_dec Z Z').

    destruct Xdec, Ydec, Zdec.

    left; split; rewrite e; rewrite e0; rewrite e1; auto.
    right; left; intro; inversion H; auto.
    right; left; intro; inversion H; auto.
    right; left; intro; inversion H; auto.
    right; left; intro; inversion H; auto.
    right; left; intro; inversion H; auto.
    right; left; intro; inversion H; auto.
    right; left; intro; inversion H; auto.
Defined.

Fixpoint extract {A B : type} (expr : term B) (val : term A) : term (A-->B).
Proof.
  pose (ab_dec := eq_term_dec expr val).
  destruct ab_dec.

  (* expr is equal to val *)
  apply fst in p; rewrite p; apply I.

  (* expr is not equal to val *)
  inversion expr as [n X | X Y f x | X | X Y | Z X Y].

  (* expr is just a constant, i.e. expr = var n X *)
  apply (K[expr]).

  (* expr is a function evaluation, i.e. expr = f[x]*)
  apply (S[extract _ _ f val][extract _ _ x val]).

  (* expr is identity, i.e. expr = I *)
  rewrite H; apply (K[expr]).

  (* expr is constant function, i.e. expr = K *)
  rewrite H; apply (K[expr]).

  (* expr is constant function, i.e. expr = S *)
  rewrite H; apply (K[expr]).
Defined.

Notation X := (base_type 0).
Notation Y := (base_type 1).

Notation x := (var 0 X).
Notation y := (var 0 Y).
Notation f := (var 0 (X --> Y --> X)).

Compute extract (f[x]) x.    (* => S [K [f]] [I] *)
Compute extract (f[x][y]) x. (* => S [S [K [f]] [I]] [K [y]] *)
```